# AWS SNS text message spend limit issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, sms-gateway

In my project, I am using `AWS` transaction text messages for New Zealand. It includes a monthly spending estimate of $100. cost per message is $0.12146. However, after sending nearly 400 text messages, `AWS` `SMS` has stopped working.

In one of the graphs, it shows I have reached 99.8 (assumed this is the average `SMS` rate for the month). According to my calculation, we only spend $48.584 (400*0.12146). Could someone please explain why `AWS` stopped sending messages? Please refer to the below images for more clarifications.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to open a support ticket and ask aws why is it so, if you have the option. Otherwise get the [get the daily usage report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_usage.html) which can give you the exact cost of each sms being sent.
According to aws

> The prices below are provided for guidance only, and change frequently. Once you’ve sent some messages, use the daily usage reports to get the exact pricing per message in USD

Comment: Your correct, for my one SMS AWS takes as Two message part therefore  it costs 2 * 0.12146 ($0.24292)